# Same layout for serverside rendered data and client side rendered data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, layout

I'm bulding a webpage with an search form. The first page of the result set is rendered on server site and send to the client (PHP->HTML->browser).

The search result contains an description with some metadata, like caption, date, ...
If the client scrolls through the search result an if he reached the end of the page, the next result rows are loaded using ajax (endless scrolling).
The ajax request received the search result in JSON format. This means without layout / style structure.

This means, I have to bring the result data in an layout structure on client side/javascript, which means, I have to place all the layout stuff on an second place, outsight the PHP world,  insight the javascript part of the application.

On the other hand, I can not simple replace the JSON data to HTML code, because I need the pure JSON search result on other parts for the webseite. The caption-metadata are the only parts, which could be HTML formatted from server side.

So my problem is: the layout for the first result set is located on server side in PHP code, while all additional loaded results, coming from ajax call, have to be designed on client/JS side.

How could i handle this, without keeping the layout on 2 different places (PHP side and Javascipt side)

My first idea was not only sending pure search result JSON data to the ajax request in order to build HTML code on server side (search metadata + layout) an send HTML snippets to ajax in JSON format:

```
{'metadata':'<h1>This is the title</h1><p>date:2017/01/01</p>'}
```

But I don't know, if that is best practice?

Comment: you could return HTML from both server-side and ajax. You could make the PHP code which generates that specific HTML into a function that you can call in both circumstances to return the markup, so you don't repeat the logic. I wouldn't embed HTML inside JSON, personally, it seems a bit pointless to have to encode and then decode it again. If you simply return HTML direct from the ajax call you can write it directly into your page with no extra work.

Comment: The reason, why the ajax request return JSON data is, because I need the search result data for more than only one "thing". The layout is only needed for the metatdata part of the result set. This means: getting HTML over ajax will result in problems for other parts of the webpage, which needs the pure JSON data. Hmmm....

Comment: What else are you using it for, exactly? And, is it an option to use only ajax for your search, and ditch the server-side rendering entirely? Then you could just return pure data as JSON from the ajax, and use a HTML template to render the results. Or maybe you need two versions of the search ajax call, once which returns the data, and another which does the rendering of the data to HTML as well, so you can use the two in different places? Obviously they could share 99% of the data-fetching parts of the code, just that one would then continue to the rendering part too

Comment: I use the JSON data for displaying: number of found objects, facetting tree, deeplink to result, link to preview, ... currently I fetch all the needed data with only one "search". Splitting the result in JSON data and well-fromed HTML data would result in 2 requests, which would result in 2 search-calls. Finally I only need the caption in an layouted version. Thats way I'm thinking about the option to add an new JSON attribute: `{'caption_html':... ` which holds the caption, which results in that HTML decoding->encoding stuff (see your first comment)

Comment: can't you generate HTML on the server side to display all those found objects, though, same as for the other bits you're talking about? What makes them any different?